# BeautifulSoup output into List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping products description from a website. The product has "Old Price" and "New Price". All the products have these both except one (which has only the "New Price"). I append the values to an empty list. So there are four lists with "Product Names", "Product Old Price", "Product New Price" and "Product Reviews". When I try to make a CSV file it gives me an error "arrays must all be the same length". The reason for this error is: "Product Old Price" list has 17 entries and the other three lists have 18 entries. As explained earlier, in one product "Product Old Price" is not given. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.petplanet.co.uk/d7/dog_food"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
prod_name =[]
prod_old_price = []
prod_new_price = []
prod_reviews = []
item = soup.findAll("a", class_ = "thumbLink")
for name in item[0:15]:
    pro_name = name.get("title")
    prod_name.append(pro_name)
price = soup.findAll("span", class_ = "price right")
for prices in price:
    pro_new_price1 = prices.text
    pro_new_price = pro_new_price1.replace("آ"," ")
    prod_new_price.append(pro_new_price)
old_price = soup.findAll("span", class_ = "price-old")
for old_pri in old_price:
    pro_old_price = old_pri.text
    prod_old_price.append(pro_old_price)

reviews = soup.findAll("span", class_ = "text-prod-review-score")
for rev in reviews:
    pro_reviews = (len(rev))
    prod_reviews.append(pro_reviews)
old_price = soup.findAll("span", class_ = "price-old")
for old_pri in old_price:
    pro_old_price = old_pri.text
    prod_old_price.append(pro_old_price)

pet_products = pd.DataFrame({"Product Name": prod_name, "Product Old Price": prod_old_price, "Product New Price": prod_new_price, "Product Reviews     as # of Star": prod_reviews})
pet_products.to_csv("Pets Products.csv")
```

I want "N/A" or "None" where there is no "Product Old Price" given.
or is there any other way.
Thanks

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [mcve] Thanks | Needs more information: url, source code, more of your written ones, end expected output)

Comment: @HedgeHog Please see above complete code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommendation

Loop the products in an other way and create a `list` of `dicts` it is easier to handle I think, also use `find_all()` instead of die old version `findAll()`

### What happens?

Cause `old_price` is not in the `page_source` if there is no `sale_price` you wont find the right position to set a value of `NA` the way your searching for.

Take a look at my example - If there is no `old_price` it would raise an error but you can use this to create the `NA` values:

```
try:
    old_price = product.find("span", class_ = "price-old").get_text(strip=True)
except:
    old_price = 'NA'
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.petplanet.co.uk/d7/dog_food"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

p_data = []

for product in soup.select('div#box-scroll-content li'):
    new_price = product.find("span", class_ = "price right").get_text().replace("آ"," ")
    try:
        old_price = product.find("span", class_ = "price-old").get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        old_price = 'NA'
    
    p_data.append({
        'new_price': new_price,
        'old_price': old_price
    })
    
pd.DataFrame(p_data)
```

**Output**

```
    new_price   old_price
0   £69.99  £76.99
1   £2.19   None
2   £6.99   £11.49
3   £6.99   £10.99
4   £0.89   £1.00
```

Comment: I want to tell you that "You are great" and StackOverflow community should be proud of you.

Comment: I learn new thing from you. #box-scroll-content li. wow man

Comment: Sometimes in my opinion it is easier to use the [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to chain classes or tags it is worth a look - Have fun @SO